# Planned comparisons: t-tests vs multiple regression analysis

Tags: regression, t-test, planned-comparisons-test

I ran an experiment with three groups (one control, two experimental). Now, I am analysing the results.

I ran:

- a regression analysis (with dummy coded groups, control group put as the contrast)
- two t-tests (*control* vs *experimental 1* and *control* vs *experimental 2*)

What surprised me is that the results are not the same. They are very similar (p values are the same if you round them to the second decimal place) but not exactly the same.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. Why are the results not the same?
2. Which approach do you think is more appropriate (the t-tests or the regression analysis)? I had clear, pre-registered hypotheses regarding all possible comparisons, so let's assume I don't want any corrections for multiple comparisons.

Comment: Does Michael Lew's answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244547/apparent-contradiction-between-t-test-and-1-way-anova answer your question?

Comment: @Sointu Thank you very much :D 
The comment is interesting and overall helpful. However, I still feel that the results from t-tests and regression should be the same and still don't fully understand why they are not

Comment: What software are you using?   Welch's t-test is the default in R and compensates for unequal variance between groups; IIRC standard regression assumes constant variance .  You can get similar results to a Welch's t test if you use generalized least squares

Comment: It is difficult to provide an answer without a lot more context. I would explain *which* t-tests were used in each case, what program you used, and other relevant information which may make this post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

A one-way ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis test would be a good first approach for testing differences between treatment groups followed by pairwise t-tests or Wilcoxon rank sum tests. Both can be done with base functions in R - anova() or kruskal.test() and pairwise.t.test()/pairwise.wilcox.test()

A linear regression model would be appropriate as well (and would give similar results as ANOVA) but allows for more flexibility if you have unequal group sizes or issues with heteroskedasticity/non-normal residuals, which can be checked mostly using qqplots and residual vs. fitted plots.

Multiple linear regression also has the advantage of making it simpler to include both continuous or categorical covariates.